# Spring boot yaml property binding: collection types

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I find Spring Boot's (or spring in general) handling of yaml collections to be a bit peculiar. Collections according to [yaml specs](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963) should be written in .yaml files as:

```
myCollection: ['foo', 'bar']
```

or

```
myCollection:
  - foo
  - bar
```

But neither `@Value("${myCollection}")` annotation or `Environment.getProperty("myCollection", String[].class)` (also tried `List.class`) can read collection properties (returns null). The only method I know of that works is to use `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation described in [spring boot docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml).

The problem with `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation is that (a) it is too verbose if all I want is a single property and (b) it rely on bean injection to get an instance of the `@ConfigurationProperties` class. Under some circumstances, bean injection is not available and all we have is a reference to `Environment` (e.g: thru ApplicationContext).

In my particular case, I want to read some properties during `ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent` event, since it happens before context is built, the listener has to be manually registered and therefore, no bean injection. Via the event argument, I can get a reference to `Environment`. So, I can read other properties but cannot read collections.

A couple of "solutions" I noted (quoted because I don't find them very satisfactory):

1. Specify collections in .yaml file as `myCollection: foo, bar`. But this is not ideal because, the format isn't really yaml anymore.
2. Read individual elements using an index, for example `Environment.getProperty("myCollection[0]", String.class)`. Will require some not-so-elegant utility methods to read and put all elements into a List.

So, my questions is - What is a good way to read collection-type properties if I cannot use `@ConfigurationProperties`? Also curious why comma-separated format works but not yaml-style collections.

EDIT: corrected some typos

Comment: For properties that are more than just simple primitive values (numbers, strings, ...), `@ConfigurationProperties` is likely the most clean solution, regardless of you wanting to use it due to its verbosity.

Comment: This is also described at [SPR-11759](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11759). The reason why a comma separated list does work is because you read it as a string and use SpEL to convert it to a list by splitting it.

Answer (score 2):

Quite Frankly Spring boot application.properties and application.yaml or application.yml is meant to load configuration properties.

The `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation is designed as an abstraction to hide the implementations of configuration properties and support both .properties and .yaml/.yml.

For yaml/yml however Spring uses `org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml` library underneath to parse the file and load it to a `Properties` object inside `org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader` and a `Collection` is mapped as a `Set` not an array or `List`. So you try doing the following;

```
Environment.getProperty("myCollection", Set.class)
```